# Google App Engine and Cloud Storage API

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm tryng to get files from **Google Cloud Storage** through an **GAE** app.

I get the bucket and filename by params (a simple `HTML` form) and I call a Servlet:

```
String bucket = req.getParameter("bucket");
String filename = req.getParameter("filename");

BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory
        .getBlobstoreService();
BlobKey blobKey = blobstoreService.createGsBlobKey("/gs/" + bucket
        + "/" + filename);
blobstoreService.serve(blobKey, resp);
```

I am receiving this error, both in **localhost** and on **GAE**:

```
The API package 'blobstore' or call 'CreateEncodedGoogleStorageKey()' was not found.
```

Comment: Got the solution for this? If so please share. Even 'm facing the same issue.